# DFS algorithm with target node

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I have to use DFS algorithm for my university project.
I saw this link [DFSlink](https://www.javatpoint.com/depth-first-search-algorithm) but i face this problem.
The Depth First Search algorithm is Traversal it goes to every node in the graph but i want to define a target node when i reach to it i want to stop the algorithm

```
while (i.hasNext()) {
                int n = i.next();
                if (!visited[n]) {
                    if (n == goal) {
                        System.err.print(infoLinkedList.get(1).nameStation+":");
                        System.err.print(" |"+goal+ "| -> ");
                        return;
                    }
                    DFSUtil_BUS(n, goal, visited);
                }
            }
```

How can i do this please?

Comment: simply add a check if u have reached the target?

Comment: Add a visitor to your DFS which is called each time a node is visited.  ( This is a very useful bit of code that you should always have around ).  In the visitor throw an exception if the visited node is the target.

Comment: It's not ideal if you completely change the question after there have been answers, as they will then not correspond to your original question any more. Please ask a new question instead.

Comment: ok... sorry....

Answer (score 0):

in this modified DFS, u also pass the target you want to check
so if you have reached your desired target. you simply return

```
void DFS(int vertex, int target) {
    visited[vertex] = true; 
    System.out.print(vertex + " ");  
  
    Iterator<Integer> it = adj[vertex].listIterator();  
    while (it.hasNext()) {  
        int n = it.next();  
        if (!visited[n]) {
            if (n == target) {
                //return when u  reach the target
                return;
            }
            DFS(n, target);  
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: i did this but it keep moving to the rest of node

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually terminate the search. All you do is call the DFS recursively if the current node has not been visited. Then, regardless of whether you found your target or not, you look at the next node.

You need to add a termination into the iterator. The first thing I would do is give the DFS function a return value: return `true` if the target has been reached, and `false` if not. Then, in your loop, break out of the loop if the return value is `true`, and return that from the current run. At the end of the while-loop, return `false` by default, as you have not found the target.

Update: You have now completely changed the question. My answer applies to the first version of it.

Comment: Why different could you explain? and how can i solve it now .. thanks @Oliver Mason

Comment: @YaraAbd The current question doesn't make sense, as you've left out the function header etc.